# EntityFramework Domain Model Interface usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

So I have this domain model:

```
public abstract class PrimaryKey
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public class MyEntity : PrimaryKey
{
    public string StringProperty {get;set;}
    public MyEntity2 MyEntity2 {get;set;}
}

public class MyEntity2 : PrimaryKey
{
    public string StringProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I want to give them interfaces so that I can use them with my services that get injected. I can't just reference the domain model in the service core project because that in my opinion is backward.

So I figured this:

```
public interface IPrimaryKey
{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public interface IMyEntity : IPrimaryKey
{
    string StringProperty {get;set;}
    IMyEntity2 MyEntity2 {get;set;}
}

public interface IMyEntity2 : IPrimaryKey
{
    string StringProperty {get;set;}
}
```

So now I have my concrete classes and my interfaces. But how does my interfaces now impact my concrete classes, surely referencing `IMyEntity` will mean in the concrete class I have to define the `Id` property, but I really want my abstract class to do that to save time.

Below is as far as I got:

```
public class MyEntity : IMyEntity
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string StringProperty {get;set;}
    public IMyEntity MyEntity2 {get;set;}
}
```

How does using an abstract class work? Does it still work? or is there another programming method I have to implement?

I thought maybe this would work:

```
public class MyEntity : PrimaryKey, IMyEntity
{
   // etc, but no Id field this time
}
```

How would this work in my repository, I use interface with generics:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<List<T>> AllAsync<T>();
    Task<T> FindAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] params);
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Task<List<T>> AllAsync<T>()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    // etc
}
```

Would it have any impact?

I'm doing this because I want to abstract out the service core and domain model into a new project and use this project between the ASP.NET front end and a WCF Service. The service need only use one entity at the moment but this maybe increased at a later date.

Comment: You're digging a big hole by misusing inheritance in these examples.

Comment: Yea I'll have to agree with @KeithPayne this solution seems to be over engineered, why do you say "I can't just reference the domain model in the service core project because that in my opinion is backward" if the service core interacts with the domain I can't see a problem with this, and IMO will be an easier solution to implement and maintain

Comment: Another thought is that there are other ways of elegantly dealing with re-using code that works on a model which contains one or more attributes that must be unique across the set. I did this sort of tightly-bound self validating entity thing before. It ends up degenerating quickly into an anti-pattern, where you spend more effort writing code that solves anticipated problems, but doesn't get you closer to delivering your product.

Comment: @KeithPayne could you maybe elaborate more on how I'm misusing inheritance

Comment: The rule of thumb: inheritance is for `Is-A`, not `Has-A` relationships. `class MyEntity` is of the second type - `MyEntity` *has a* primary key. Code that you want to re-use across objects that have a `Guid Id` property does not need to live in a base class, but can be in a different class that is designed to work on `IPrimaryKey` objects. Inheritance of interfaces is less problematic.

Comment: By the way, I hope that you aren't reading too critical of a tone into these comments, I don't intend that. I'd normally use an answer to be gentler/less terse, but these comments don't really address your question.

Comment: Consider use DTO for transferring data between layers instead of making your domain models more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just like to point out, that in the domain entity, if you reference an Interface it doesn't get created in the database as a column.

So I don't think this can be done, and like Keith Payne said, it just over complicates it.